# Notepad++ detect other line ending on my 2 pcs, how can i solve this?

Tags: notepad++

On one of my pcs if i open a file, and set it to show every invisible characters the line endings are "CR LF"s if i save this file and send it to my other pc and open it, there is an empty line between every line, and the line endings are "CR CR LF".
Vica versa, if i create a document on my another pc and move to the first one. There are no line breaks at all.
In other programs (notepad, word etc. there are no problems)
Any idea where is a setting for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Notepad++ has the same line-ending settings on both computers. Access Notepad++ menu => **Settings** => **Preferences** => **New document** => **Format (line endings)**.

When the line endings in an existing document are not as expected try using Notepad++ menu => **Edit** => **EOL Conversion**.